# creating objects dynamically aka turn a string into a classname call in python

Tags: python, class

I want to pull the name of the object from a file and reload it with values I've already saved.  I'm writing my own pickle-type functions because pickle isn't doing what I want.

1. I save all user input variables to a text file.
2. I reopen my project (and textfile) and have all the user-input values still available.  Some of those variables are objects of classes I created.

To save the values in step 1, I pulled out the object's class name and all the variables associated with it.

So, knowing the class name, how do I declare a new object and load up all my saved variables? In other words, how do I turn a string into a classname to initiate a new object?

```
cn = myclassname
```

to

```
newobj = cn()
```

Comment: " I'm writing my own pickle-type functions because pickle isn't doing what I want." This seems like a terrible idea. What exactly isn't working with `pickle`? Whatever you create here will be a worse version of `pickle`.

Comment: I've been programming for a long time.  One way is not necessarily worst than another and if I write it myself, I have more control.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do:

- Your classes should be able to export the parameters you want to store in a dictionary. Use the inspect module and a mixin class for this.
- Store the dicts in a yaml/json format; dicts are handled really nice. Keys are the classnames. Multiple objects of the same class come in lists.
- Create a class just for recreating the objects. This should have a lookup table (a dictionary) with the names of the classes as dict, the classes as value. Iterate the dict read from the file and create the objects.

Comment: "Use the inspect module and a mixin class for this." why would that be necessary?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Not to have to extend all classes with the same code that are to be exported.